# How to make a drag & drop functionality in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid layout defined in Xaml in Xamarin Forms. I want to achieve a drag and drop functionality like in this example : http://gridstackjs.com/

Can someone please help to achieve this or provide an example ? I am totally stuck with this. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.xamboy.com/2017/08/23/draggable-view-in-xamarin-forms/ may be this what you're looking for

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT : Bro, can you help me achieve this drag & drop in a simple way ? https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms